# Is Apache Camel available in AmazonMQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, apache-camel-aws, amazon-mq

**Disclaimer**: I did post this on Server Fault, first, and the replies there were:

- > I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not AWS support.
- > This question does not appear to be about server, networking, or related infrastructure administration within the scope defined in the help center.

I think this is a valid question, and even first-party support can be found on the Stack Exchange network. I think issues/limitations are easier to find on SO than on the multitude of AWS 'documentation'. This is why I'm posting this question on SO.

## The issue/question

From what I've found on the AWS documentation and the limited subset of Apache ActiveMQ configuration elements, I haven't found how to use the Camel plugin that is supposed to be built into newer versions of ActiveMQ. I figure this is left out of the AmazonMQ version, or is blocked by the configuration limitations.

[This is the list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-broker-configuration-parameters.html) of available configuration elements.  Their configuration document's root element is `<broker>`, and it looks like camel is supposed to be configured as a sibling to that node an a traditional ActiveMQ config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camel "plugin" is actually simply an imported Spring configuration file that fires up Camel. AmazonMQ does not, as to my understanding, permit imported configuration files hence running an embedded Camel is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Camel is not supported today running within the Amazon MQ broker itself, however here is a blog showing how to use Camel with Amazon MQ.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/integrating-amazon-mq-with-other-aws-services-via-apache-camel

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)